# Azure Devops, Single Line Text Character Limit?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a Single Line Text field type from a customized Work item Type that for some reason is cutting off long URL's. I am wondering if there is a character limitation. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4):

> I am wondering if there is a character limitation. Does anyone know?

The answer is **Yes**.

The default String fields take a max of **255** characters. You could use **PlainText** Text field type instead of the default String field, which supports entry of **a text string that can contain more than 255 Unicode characters**.

You can check the document [FIELD (Definition) element reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/field-definition-element-reference?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#attributes-and-elements) for some more details:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note, PlainText is not available in DevOps Services, only in on-premise DevOps Server :(